# How to match a variable in statement?

Tags: python

I would like to use a variable fetch_name to match the condition. If match found then run the def range_func() function or else its should continue to run other script function.

```
pre_confif ={}
pre_confif['pre_confif']= "flow/config/mode/"+fetch_name+"/boundary/"+type+".json"

if fetch_name == 'deploy' 

# if match found then run this function
    def range_func():
        #do something
else:
    # should continue to run rest of the script
```

Comment: `def` *defines* a function which can then be run afterwards.

Comment: What *specific* problem are you having with this script?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would want to do that:

```
def rnge():
    # Function code here

if fetch_name == 'deploy':
    rnge()
else:
    # Do something else
```

Note that you want to **def**ine your function outside of the if statement, and simply make a call to it inside of the if block. Also, you should avoid using "range" as a function name, as it is a built-in python function.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to define a function above main code and call it. Also do not use python pre-defined methods names as function name or variable name.

```
def range_func():
  return 


pre_confif={}
pre_confif['pre_confif']="flow/config/mode/"+fetch_name+"/boundary/"+type+".json"

fetch_name = input()

if fetch_name == 'deploy':
    result = range_func()
    print(result)
else:
    print('Not deploy')
    # should continue to run rest of the script
```